# Proving Mathematical Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

I have the following exercise which I am trying to understand:

**For which nonnegative integers $n$ is $2n + 3 ≤ 2^n$? Prove
your answer.**

I know that we first have to inspect for the basis case and so we find that $n > 3$, since $n=1,2,3$ do not hold but $4$ plus does, so $n > 3.$ But for the Induction step I don't understand how to start it and the textbook solution is unclear, could anyone explain to me what this means?

**Textbook solution:** For the inductive step assume that $P(k)$ is true. Then, by the
inductive hypothesis, $2(k + 1) + 3 = (2k + 3) + 2 < 2^k + 2.$
But because $k ≥ 1 , 2^k + 2 ≤ 2^k + 2^k = 2^k+1$. This shows that
$P(k+1)$ is true.

Comment: Please use math latex formatting. 

1) Show it’s true for $P(4)$. 2) that $P(k)$ implies $P(k+1)$ 3) conclude it’s true for all $k\geq 4$ by induction.

Comment: Can you state explicitly which part of the solution is not clear to you?

Comment: The Induction part is not clear to me, i dont understand how they got to 2^k+2 then 2^k+1.

Comment: The $(2k+3)+2<2^k+2$ comes from applying the induction hypothesis that $2k+3<2^k$.

Comment: Ok so far i understand that if we expand 2(k+1)+3 we get 2k+2+3 but why does the right side of the inequality have +2? shouldn't it have been 2^k+1?

Comment: If you are having trouble with the notion of mathematical induction itself, you could look at this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581127/the-concept-of-mathematical-induction?rq=1) or [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Answer (score 1):

$$2^1<2^2<\cdots<2^k$$ Hence $$2^k +2<2^k+2^k=2\cdot 2^k=2^{k+1}$$

Comment: Could you please explain where the +2 came from?

Comment: You said in your question $$2(k+1)+3=(2k+3)+2=2^k+2$$

Comment: So basically 2(k+1)+3 = 2k+3+2 then 2k+3 = 2^k then you add the +2? I feel stupid but how did you get 2k+3 to be 2^k?

Comment: Have you done inductive proofs before? This is what we call the “inductive hypothesis”… in other words we are assuming it to be true for that $k\in \mathbf{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you have two functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, 
where for all $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, you have that $0 < f(n), g(n),$ 
and you establish a base case $n_0 \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that $f(n_0) < g(n_0),$ 
you then have two separate strategies that you might follow 
to inductively prove that for all $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that $n \geq n_0,$ 
it is true that $f(n) < g(n)$.

---

The first strategy would be to examine the general ratios:

$\displaystyle R_n = \frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}, ~S_n = \frac{g(n+1)}{g(n)}.$

If you can show that for all $n \in \Bbb{Z^+},$ such that $n \geq n_0$, 
that $0 < R_n < S_n$, then you can reason as follows:

Suppose that $f(n) < g(n)$. 
Then, you also have that $f(n+1) = R_n \times f(n)$ 
and $g(n+1) = S_n \times g(n)$.

Therefore, since $0 < f(n) < g(n)$ and $0 < R_n < S_n,$ 
then $R_n \times f(n) < S_n \times g(n).$

---

The second strategy is very similar to the first strategy, except that instead of focusing on **ratios**, you focus on **differences**.

That is, 
let $F_n$ denote $f(n+1) - f(n)$ and 
let $G_n$ denote $g(n+1) - g(n)$.

Suppose that you can show that for all $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ 
such that $n \geq n_0$, you have that 
$F_n < G_n$.

Then, you can reason as follows:

Assume that $f(n) < g(n)$. 
Then, $f(n+1) = F_n + f(n)$ 
and $g(n+1) = G_n + g(n)$. 
Then, because $f(n) < g(n)$ and $F_n < G_n$ 
you have that $F_n + f(n) < G_n + g(n).$

---

The second strategy above is what the offered solution focused on, differences.

> To prove: 
> For all $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ let $f(n) = 2n + 3$ and let $g(n) = 2^n.$ 
> Then for all $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that $n \geq 4$ 
> $f(n) < g(n)$.

First, the assertion was manually verified for $n = 4$.

Then, (in effect), the offered solution noted that 
$F_n = f(n+1) - f(n) = [2(n + 1) + 3] - [2(n) + 3] = 2.$
$G_n = g(n+1) - g(n) = 2^{n+1} - 2^n = 2^n.$

Then, the offered solution noted that for $n \geq 4$, you have that: 
$F_n < G_n$.

This conclusion allowed the second strategy above, that focuses on differences, to be invoked.

Comment: I understand how you did it but the method we are following from the textbook is different i believe.

Comment: @MathStudy1 The only difference between the textbook approach and my Strategy 2, is that the textbook (in effect) said that $f(n) + F(n) < g(n) + F(n) < g(n) + G(n).$