Understanding Analysis - Question about redundant proof by induction
(I've read this already. The accepted answer just reiterates what came from the book.)
Hi all, am new to this.
$x_{n+1} = {1\over2} x_n + 1$ & $x_1 = 1$
Abbott wants to prove that $x_n \leq x_{n+1}$.
As in: "Let's use induction to prove that this trend continues; that is, let's show that
$x_n \leq x_{n+1}$
for all values of $n \in \Bbb N$."
Now he multiplies the inequality by $1\over2$ and adds $1$ ending at ${1\over2} x_n + 1 \leq {{1\over2} x_{n+1} + 1}$. Now this simplifies to $x_{n+1} \leq x_{n+2}$. This proves that $x_{n+1} \leq x_{n+2}$.
But this is the weird part. He wants to prove the inequality to be true but uses the inequality to do it? He has yet to prove the inequality $x_n \leq x_{n+1}$. If he doesn't, then you might as well take the route of it always being true. But if you do that, why show that $x_{n+1} \leq x_{n+2}$?
He calls this original equation a "hypothesis", meaning: it is taken as true. Well, you don't need to do anything if you already assume it to be true though. This is already an induction-based principle, since $n+1$ is already larger than $n$ in this inequality...

Forgive my ignorance fellow humans. I am new to this and have pondered many a time on this question. I would appreciate it very kindly if anyone was to help me with this!

read this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/626648

Hello @psl2Z I've read the post you've linked. Poster specifically addresses the "confusing part". I can see what he means and how you think it answers my question. Now I am still confused. Abbott calls $x_n \leq x_{n+1}$ a 'hypothesis'. This means its already true. You need not prove anything else. Why bother still?

There's two parts to it: you show it's true for the very first $n$, and then show that if it were true for some $n$, then it's true for $n+1$. Logically, this shows that the property is true for all $n$ by propagation.

@BrunoB Hello. I have read what you've said. Abbott also includes these two principles (i) & (ii). I understand them and how they support conclusions based on these principles. But my question may be different.

Abbott is not assuming that the inequality is already true for all $n$, only for one single fixed $n$, and then shows that the inequality is then true for $n+1$.

Hello @BrunoB. But I thought $n \in \Bbb N$. Meaning, there is no fixed $n$. This is already an induction-style statement, such that assuming it to be true reflects the nature of induction-based proofs. It is already a part of the statement when we call the end result true.

The claim is true for $n=1$. Abbott has shown that if $x_n\leq x_{n+1}$, then $x_{n+1}\leq x_{n+2}$. In particular, taking $n=1$, we see $x_2\leq x_3$. Taking $n=2$, se see $x_3\leq x_4$, and so on.

Maybe it'll be clearer with quantifiers: what Abott is trying to show here is that $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, (x_n \leq x_{n+1}) \Rightarrow (x_{n+1} \leq x_{n+2})$$ (along with having shown that $x_0 \leq x_1$) as a middle step to prove that $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x_{n} \leq x_{n+1}$$ The former statement requires assuming that for any given but fixed $n$, the inequality is true, and show it's true for $n+1$, you don't assume it's true for all $n$ at once.

Hello and thank you for your respones. I have understood already that the $n+2$ case is proven not by itself, but as any $n$ being smaller than or equal $n+1$. Showing that this specific property (not of being true, but of being smaller than or equal to) is true for all $n$ as a consequence. But this was done by using a statement that was already assumed true. But the assumed statement already shows what the new statement shows. Does it not? That is my question.

In order to not bloat the comment section too much, let me try to answer you in as clear terms as possible, or at least what I hope will be clear enough.
What you do is take a single fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, one at a time, and assume for that specific $n$ only that it satisfies $P(n): x_n \leq x_{n+1}$.
If you don't like the "overloading" of $n$ as a notation, that is if you only see $n$ as a mysterious unfixable unknown, you can name this particular $n$ $n_0$ instead.
Now, in this context you have a way to prove that if $P(n_0)$ is true, which we've merely assumed for this chosen $n_0$ and no other $n$, then $P(n_0 + 1)$ is true, which wasn't assumed nor known to be true beforehand, meaning you got fresh new information. But the kicker is that the method of proof didn't depend on ulterior properties of $n_0$, hence it's true for any $n_0$ you could possibly have chosen, thus:
$$\forall n_0 \in \mathbb{N},\quad P(n_0) \Rightarrow P(n_0 + 1)$$
This by itself does not mean that we've proven that $P(n_0)$ and $P(n_0 + 1)$ are true, but that for all $n_0$, if we assume $P(n_0)$ specifically to be true, then we could prove from that assumption alone that $P(n_0 + 1)$ is true.
Since it's been proven separately that $P(0)$ is true without making assumptions, this implies that, taking $n_0 = 0$, we have a true proof that $P(1)$ is true, and so on and so forth.
The use of different synonyms or equivalent expressions was not done with malicious intent, I just wanted to get my point across that Abott is not doing a circular argument by assuming before the proof that the whole result is true.

The way we learnt induction in our high school it always told us that let us suppose the statement $P(n) $ is True for $n=m$ and then using this show that it is True for $n=m+1$. So yes a different variable was used to avoid confusion. +1
